# CSV files, creating lists from a CSV file, and perform a search for data

Tags: python, csv

I'm having a little toruble with making this program for my assignment I'm suppossed to search if a pre-registered player appears in the list or not, find the number of a specific player, print a list of players and their information, and use at least one if-else or elif statement. I access the data by importing the "battle_royale.csv" file.

The output of the code is suppossed to look like this:
[image]

This is all I have so far:

```
def main():
   
   avatarNames = [”LarchDew15”,”Pinerain2”,”xOakenMaidx”,”Grandidel”,”Gened123”,”Tufty98”,”silverstar”,”grimRAVEN”,”fogdell”,”111marshglitter111”,
   ”1337Vale”,”pinesword”,”GreyLore”,”silveneye90””Shaewaith1999”,”ronar”,”yulnul”,”durowen”,”glyrgrim”,”Goghyll55”,
   ”Welriel21”,”Glanros0000”,”Lochach2000”,”Ashioth”,
   ”ashrar12”,”immain_321”,”kwelnar”,”Talzak01”,”Lirzen”,”Yoraish555",
   ”Renryl”,”ghuluith000”,”ryzenfire”,”gryffenford”,”collock”,
   ”sidwick2005”,”fayrewater”,”beestelonde”,”mucktor1x1”,”dwalegarth”,
   ”namankol”,”qigomx0x”,”Iderdizan2001”,”bulbascore100”,”enaux0x0x0”,
   ”yojugo1001”,”sayeon121”,”yabu111”]
   playerNames = [”Emily”,”Hannah”,”Madison”,”Jacob”,”Micheal”,”Matthew”,”Ashley”,”Sarah”,”Christopher”,”Alexis”,”Nicholas”,”Samantha”,
 ”Andrew”,”Javier”,”Caleb”,”Hunter”,”Nicholas”,”Samantha”,”Andrew”,
”Jessica”,”Taylor”,”Daniel”,”Tyler”,”Joshua”,”Elizabeth”,”Billy”,”Olivia”,”Ethan”,”Abigail”,”Emma”,“Alexander”,”Isabella”,”Sophia”,”Xavier”,“Maya”,”Landon”,”Owen”,”Devin”,“Jocelyn”,“Diego”,
“Cody”,”Damian”,”Zoey”,”Sadie”,”Travis”,”Eli”,”Colin”,“Braden”,”Quinn”,”Conner”,”Cassidy”,
”Riley”,”Morgan”,”Javier”,”Caleb”,”Hunter”]
   playerNumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]
   
   print(”Welcome to the Battle Royale Game Tournament Registration”)
   print(”  ****************Main Menu****************”)
   options = input(”A: find pre-registered player ; B: Find the number of a specific player ; C: Print lists of player ; Q: Quit/Log out   Please enter your choice:”)
   
main()
```

Comment: Do you want to ask a question about your code?

Comment: yes, how would I use if and elif statements for each choice in the main menu

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to use `if` and `elif`?

Comment: Im not sure how to use it with a csv file. If user chose A from the main menu i'm not sure how i would tell the program to search for a pre registered player

Comment: Maybe you start by writing a program that prints "you chose A" when the user entered "a", "you chose B" when the user entered "b" and "you chose nothing" when the user entered anything else. Forget about CSV files and player numbers for a moment until this works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), can't go wrong here:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv", columns=["Avatar_Names", "Player Number"])
if df["Avatar_Names"].isin([avatar_name]):
   do_stuff()
```

However, you can also use the [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

```py
import csv

data = []
with open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    dataset = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in dataset:
        data.append(row)

do_stuff_with_data()
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a csv file in the same directory as my python script. This is a screenshot of the sheet:

[image: Excel Sheet]

The name of the excel file is test_book.csv.

If I use the code below:

```
import csv

def main():
   with open('test_book.csv') as csv_file: # Opens the book
       csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

       for idx, row in enumerate(csv_reader): # Looping through each line with a value
           if idx > 0:
               print("The username is %s, the name is %s and the number is %s" %(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

It gives me:

[image]

If I'm looking for a user, I can use the following code:

```
import csv

def main():
    user_choice = input("Please give the number of the user you wish to search for: ")
    with open('test_book.csv') as csv_file: # Open the book
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') # Read the file

        for row in csv_reader: # Loop through the book
            if row[2] == user_choice: # Row[2] is the third column along - since indexes start at 0
                print("The username is %s, the name is %s and the number is %s" %(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

And now I get:

[image]